# solving a 2D eigenvalue problem for a partial differential equation

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method, eigenvalues, boundary-conditions

I'm fairly new to Mathematica and I'm looking for a way to solve a partial differential equation subject to periodic boundary conditions. The form of the equation looks like this:

$\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}F(x,y) + \frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2}F(x,y) + \frac{\partial}{\partial x}F(x,y) + \frac{\partial}{\partial y}F(x,y) + \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x \partial y}F(x,y) + G(x,y)F(x,y) = K F(x,y)$

where in that equation, the function $G(x,y)$ is non-separable, therefore making it impossible to recast the problem into two separate ODEs. I want to be able to solve this numerically by assuming that

$F(x,y) = \sum_{n}k_n f_{n}(x,y)$

So how do I go about doing this in mathematica? I assume I cant do this with NDSolve right?

Comment: If you make a series ansatz, you should specify the fn(x,y) .

Comment: @jboy Can you define $G(x,y)$?

Comment: @Alex Trounev its a complicated expression involving terms of cos(ax) and cos(by). Which isnt separable into two functions of only x and only y.

Comment: @Daniel Huber What if i dont go with the series ansatz? Is there a way to solve an eigenvalue problem like this in mathematica?

Comment: A series ansatz is o.k. But then you must give the fn's and determine the kn's